# how to implement pusher presence authentication callback in javascript

Tags: javascript, authentication, callback, pusher

I have set my pusher object for the destination authentication request

```
Pusher.channel_auth_endpoint = '/php/pusher_auth.php';
```

Is here a js callback event so that I could display an ajax loading gif while pusher is authenticating and show a div after pusher auth is successful and done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following docs for the authentication process and example code: http://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users

You can bind to the `pusher:subscription_succeeded` to know when the subscription has successfully been registered with Pusher. You can bind to the `pusher:subscription_error` event to be informed when the subscription fails. See:
http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_events#subscription_error

Comment: thanks , how about when an "subscribing" even when the user is being authenticated. is there an existing event?

Comment: @bman that doesn't exist, no. Just 1. the action of subscribing 2. the auth error event and 3. the subscription succeeded events.